# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'iop.servicecategories' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `servicecategories`)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, orm

I have a problem with this error so there are my table and model

[image]

[image]

I try to put this in my model:

```
 protected $table = 'servicecategories';
```

but the problem is not solved.

also try to clear cache and delete table but the problem is not solved,
also if i try to make a simple php artisan

Comment: Did you verify that the table was created in the database?

Comment: hi lucas, is not, it says this  A table was not found: You might have forgotten to run your migrations. You can run your migrations using `php artisan migrate`. but if i try it say the error 42s02 (the error in the title)

Comment: Hi @Lordp and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to be easy to read, with proper formatting, with code snippets pasted in the body and a clear description of the problem. This will make it easier for contributors to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because you used model or function other in **AppServiceProvider**. You need comment it before call **migrate**

Comment: Yes, that was the problem with one of my Laravel installations. I commented out the relevant code in AppServiceProvider, ran the migration and then uncommented the relevant code again and now I can migrate without this error message.

Answer (score 0):

Please run command => php artisan migrate

Comment: Hi Venkata and welcome to Stack Overflow. It'd be helpful to add some context to your answer to explain why it should fix the problem and also formatting code with backticks will make it easier to read. More on [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and on [Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

In db ..Your table name is different from your class name. I think they both should be the same  I think this is the problem  ..
When you run
php artisan migrate works?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `php artisan migrate:fresh` to rewrite all your db based on existing migration code you have done

Answer (score 0):

It means the database was created but the tables were not.
For Laravel applications, you need to migrate the tables like so ;

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score -1):

In your migration you are using a common class, but Laravel uses anonymous classes.

Replace

```php
class CreateServicecategoriesTable extends Migration {
```

With

```php
return new class extends Migration {
```

Comment: This is absolutely relative... Depends on the Laravel version and the author did not specify which one he/she is using...